# Why does this unix shell code work like this?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a `bash` script containing a line like the following:

```
echo 2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality
```

I'm trying to understand why I don't get the output following the `echo` sent to the screen.

Instead, *nothing* is output to the screen, and there's be a new file, with the name `5` , containing `2`, the names of all files in my current directory, and the string `3 is a valid inequality`.

Why does this happen? Can someone explain? By the way, I am running this in a Linux system.

Comment: I suggest you **read** the **manual** of your shell before trying to use it. One does not shave oneself with a chainsaw just because "I didn't know I shouldn't"...

Comment: Speak for yourself, @H2CO3. I prefer to live on the edge. So to speak.

Comment: Got it. Created some files like 2xyz, 2abc. The code puts all file names whose name is of the type 2<<Something>> and also the number 3 into (using >) a (automatically created) file named 5. It also adds the string - "is a valid inequality" to file 5.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - how about less punishment. +1 perhaps to soften the blow ?

Comment: @H2CO3 - how about less punishment. +1 perhaps to soften the blow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell first processes input/output redirections like `> 5` and attaches the relevant file handles to the file it opens (`5` in this case).

It also expands `*` into the matching files in the current directory. So what you end up with is:

```
echo 2 <<ALL YOUR FILES>> is a valid inequality
```

where the output is sent to your previously opened file.

If you want the literal string to be output, you need to tell the shell not to do its normal interpretation:

```
echo '2 * 3 > 5 is a valid inequality'
```

Comment: Wait what? Why the downvote? This answer is absolutely correct!

Comment: Got it. Created some files like 2xyz, 2abc. The code puts all file names whose name is of the type 2<<Something>> and also the number 3 into (using >) a (automatically created) file named 5. It also adds the string - "is a valid inequality" to file 5.

Answer (score 3):

The `>` is redirecting standard output.

The `*` is expanded to all (non-hidden) file names

Read the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).